# Mozilla не передает асинхронно форму обработчику во фрейм

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, асинхронность

Почему код

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
            form.method = "post";
            form.action = "handler.php";
            form.enctype = "multipart/form-data";               
            form.submit();
```

работает в браузерах Гугл Хром, Опера и Сафари, а в FF для его работы нужно добавлять явно объект form в DOM перед отправкой формы?

```
document.body.appendChild(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно добавляйте объект FORM в DOM